# How to add new attributes to existing data in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating an app in Android Studio, which will allow a registered users to book trips. For this case, I have 2 activities: DepartGermany and DepartGermany2.

In the first activity a new Trip node is created, containing 3 attributes: city, zip, street.

In the second activity I want the user to add a phone number and a name to the same "Trip" ID. How would you recommend me to do this?

Below is the code for the first activity, which is working fine. Thank you in advance!

```
public class DepartGermany extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spinnerCity;

    EditText editTextZIP;
    EditText editTextStreet;

    Button buttonAdd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_depart_germany);

        spinnerCity = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.selectCountries);
        editTextZIP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextZIP);
        editTextStreet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStreet);
        buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);


        String currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

        databaseTrips = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("TripsAll").child(currentUser);

        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addTrip();
            }
        });
    }

    private void addTrip(){
        String city = spinnerCity.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
        String zip = editTextZIP.getText().toString().trim();
        String street = editTextStreet.getText().toString().trim();

    String id = databaseTrips.push().getKey();

        Trips trip = new Trips(
                city,
                zip,
                street
        );

    databaseTrips.child(id).setValue(trip);

        Intent intent = new Intent(DepartRomania.this, DepartGermany2.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to know the key/ID of the trip that you want to add data to. Once you do that, updating the node with the new properties is a matter of:

```
HashMap<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("phonenumber", "+1-800-555-6789");
values.put("name", "Name of the trip");
databaseTrips.child(id).updateChildren(values);
```